# How to detect if user has left the app?

Tags: android

I am developing an android app which has multiple activities. I have added a soundtrack also. What I want is to keep playing sound when user is switching between activities but as soon as user leaves it should stop. Help me please

Comment: check out the following documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: you can use service

Answer (score 0):

To navigate transitions between stages of the activity lifecycle, the Activity class provides a core set of six callbacks: onCreate(), onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), onStop(), and onDestroy(). The system invokes each of these callbacks as an activity enters a new state. Fore more information click [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Figure 1 presents a visual representation of this paradigm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To work some thing in the background , you need to use the **Service**.

for example you may refer :[this sample from Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer)

In the above code Find How `MusicService` used to achieve your problem. for more search "Android service example".. hope it helps..

[MusicService link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/MusicService.java)